# choice : Dropbox.dropbox Dropbox.client class

Tags: download, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have to develop a small daemon, using flask and Dropbox API, that downloads files from my Dropbox account to my local database.
It is my first contact with the Dropbox API. 
So I am confused in the choice of the class that I should use: 
`Dropbox.dropbox` class or `Dropbox.client` class?!
What is the difference between the two classes?! 
and what the best use for each class?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`dropbox.Dropbox` class](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox). That uses the current version of the Dropbox API, which is API v2.

The `client` class is offered for backwards compatibility, and uses the [deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/) API v1.

Comment: The probleme that i need sthg like this
dbx.get_file(t)
which is not found in dropbox.Dropbox class

Comment: You can use [`files_download`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download) to get the file data like that.